# Calculate bounding size to fit rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, discrete-mathematics, rectangles

I hope I have phrased my question correctly.

Let's assume I have a rectangle with a `width` and `height` of `X` and `Y`.
Then I pick an aspect ratio of `0.56`.
How can I calculate the size of the rectangle that bounds the original rectangle, without shrinking it?

In other words, I want to keep the original rectangle as is, and "place" it inside a canvas that obeys the aspect ratio, I'm trying to calculate the canvas size.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Roi

Comment: If I have understood your question. it suffices to preserve the ratio H/W=0.56.

Comment: @gimusi Yes. The canvas ratio should be the selected ratio.

Comment: What is your fixed dimension for H or W or for the Area?

Comment: Assuming you have aspect ratio is height over width, then I think you would need a rectangle of size $\max(X, Y/0.56)\times\max(Y,0.56 X)$. See if that works.

Comment: The fixed dimension is the source rectangle (I'm building an app, the source rectangle is the video rectangle which I'm trying to "fit" inside a canvas)

Comment: @AdrianKeister Will this work both for width > height || height > width || width = height?

Comment: @gimusi see two comment above

Comment: Yeah, checking that out now. You might actually need to try something like this: `if Y > 0.56 X then (Y/0.56, Y) else (X, 0.56X)`. That should definitely work.

Comment: What is (Y/0.56, Y), Sorry for the ignorance. Is it Y/0.56 * Y?

Comment: Sorry: my notation here means `(width, height)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79353/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-adrian-keister).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x, y$ be the dimensions of the window that you want to fit into a canvas with aspect ratio $r$. Let the desired dimensions of the canvas be $x', y'$. In all cases, we must have $y'/x' = r$. Three cases:

- if $y/x = r$, then both dimensions fit just right: let $x' = x, y' = y$.
- if $y/x > r$, the rectangle is tall, so we fit the y-dimension: $y' = y$ and since $y'/x' = r$, we have $y/x' = r \implies x'= y/r$.
- if $y/x < r$, then we fit the x-dimension: $x' = x$ and since $y'/x' = r$, we have $y'/x = r \implies y' = xr$.

Comment: I tried for hours to solve it, but i just saw that you said y' / x' = r, where I tried the opposite lol.  Thank you sir!